# Extracting package version by grepping output of rpm -qi [package-name] with regular expression

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Why does regex `rpm -qi rpm-build | grep -E [[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+$`  return

[image]

? Isn't the regex supposed to match periods with `\.` ? If so why is not the first match the only one returned ?

Comment: Solved with the following `sed` workaround: `rpm -qi rpm-build | grep Version | sed 's/Version\s+:\s+//'`

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Comment: @Kusalananda: i wanted to benefit from the colored output. Still want me to remove it and leave a text output instead ?

Comment: While the red highlighting helps point out the matches, I think it'd be obvious enough to anyone who's paying attention that two of the three lines don't have periods in them, leading to your confusion about trying to match the periods. It would also help any future answerers by giving them copy/paste-able text to test their Answers with (I manually typed in some sample data as a workaround).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't quoted the regular expression, so your shell processed the two backslashes. As a result, `grep` saw this regular expression: `[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+$` which indeed matches. Quote the expression:

```
rpm -qi rpm-build | grep -E '[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+$'
```

If you really just want the version information from `rpm -q`, ask for it directly with `--queryformat`, and skip the grep:

```
version=$(rpm -q --queryformat '%{VERSION}' rpm-build)
```

Comment: Just why is it that without quoting bash interprets the backslash ? It's a bash special character ? And bash here is simply stripping it off, ignoring it ?

Comment: That's its job :) https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/html_node/Escape-Character.html#Escape-Character -- in case you want to use *another* special character without its special meaning, such as `*` or `$`, etc. The shell doesn't particularly care about plain periods here, so yes, it strips/processes the backslash before handing it all over to `grep`.